# convert const char* to NSString * and convert back - _NSAutoreleaseNoPool()

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i'm trying to convert const char*  to NSString * and then convert it back. It works, but i get:

```
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100550a40 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100551730 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100551f10 of class NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

The code is:

```
const char* convert = "hello remove this: *";

NSString *input = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:convert];// convert 

//remove * FROM THE STRING          
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*"]; 

// REPLACE * WITH NOTHING                   
input = [[input componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];

// CONVERT BACK         
const char *converted_back = [input UTF8String];
```

I'm lost, please help me out.

Comment: Show all your code, I think I know what the problem is but I need to check your whole code first.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are doing it in a background thread, add an NSAutoReleasePool.

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
const char* convert = "hello remove this: *";
NSString *input = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:convert] autorelease];// convert 
//remove * FROM THE STRING          
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*"]; 
// REPLACE * WITH NOTHING                   
input = [[input componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
// CONVERT BACK         
const char *converted_back = [input UTF8String]; 
[pool drain];
```

Also, you need to release `input` after you're done with it, or make it autoreleased.

Comment: i'm doing it in a headerfile then i include/import it inside the NSApplicationDelegate souce, could you show me a example, becouse i'm new to this..

Comment: im getting Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: How do you find the point? but it says: [Switching to process 640]
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
[Switching to process 640]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all

Comment: Fixed it, it was a problem with the thread, but your code made it also works, thanks!